# How to remove specific elements using the removeChild

Tags: javascript, web-applications, aframe, removechild

generating load chunks with the following code:

```
function loadChunk (ndx){
            var passId = "zChunk" + ndx;
            var zPos = ndx * 24;
            var addEl = document.createElement('a-entity');
            addEl.setAttribute("id", passId);
            addEl.setAttribute("gltf-model", "#bound");
            addEl.object3D.position.set(0, 0, zPos);
            sceneEl.appendChild(addEl);
        }
```

now I am trying to remove chunks too far away from me:

```
        function stepLoad(cPos){
        
            if (cPos / 24 - loadId < 0.5){
            return;
            }
            else if(cPos > loadId){
            loadId ++;
            loadChunk(loadId + 12);
            console.log('load');
            sceneEl.removeChild(getElementById("zChunk" + (loadId -13)));
            //retrieve chunk with (loadId - 12) and unload it
            }
            else{
            return;
            }
        };
```

cPos is camera position.

loadId is keeping track of what I have currently loaded.

So for now where ignoring that there is no code for loading and unloading in the other direction, which will be inside the else statement. Right now I am looking at  sceneEl.removechild, where I fail to generate a proper reference to the element with the id "zChunk-13". I have checked, the generated element has the proper Id. I'm guessing it has something to do with nesting math in a getElementById nested inside removechild, even if I could make it work with different syntax, I would prefer something cleaner. Any fixes?

Comment: `"zChunk" + (loadId -13)` will evaluate to `"zChunk-13"` only if `loadId == 26`. It's not clear what you try to calculate in that line with `(loadId - 13)`. How is `loadId` related to the `id` or the postfix (`-13`)?

Comment: Elements indexed roughly between +12 and -12 start in a loaded state. I'm myself still trying to wrap my head around this code, so please have patience, and I am open to a rework if that's needed. These elements are 3d models that load an endless corridor 24 meters at a time. I'm treating these models as javascript objects that loads  other 3d components within its bounds as appendChild code. And there are additional properties for needed code associated with assets and implementation / metadata. Any recommendations relating to lazy loading or other soft loading methods are also welcome.

Comment: by this code getElementById("zChunk" + (loadId -13))); I hoped to get the value for the corrisponding object that i wanted to unload, and then .removechild () would have removed it. Thats not working for me...

Comment: I just noticed that you call `getElementById(..)` instead of `document.getElementById(..)`, which should be not defined - at least not by default.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have solved my main problem, revealed a few errors, but that's to be expected. I will accept a missing document object as my error. Do you want to submit it and get the credit? Also I am still open to more efficient code if you find my attempts in any way misguided or clumsy.

Comment: Well i'm glad I could help - at least in part. However, i'm not familiar with A-Frame and I can't help you with rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById()` is a method of the [`document`](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp.html) object. Hence you should call `document.getElementById()` instead.